# TouchStart, TouchMove, TouchEnd not firing if the start of the Touch was outside of the touchscreen?

Tags: javascript, css, cordova

In my app I have a div that is of 100% width and starting at `top: 50%;left:0px`. I have implemented a touchStart/Move/End handler that is working very well, but only if I start the touch-gesture on the screen.

If I start from off the screen and slide my finger into the screen the events do not fire.

Neither the touchStart-Handler nor the touchMove-Handler fire, if, the touch started outside of the touchscreen. I have trouble debugging this, but maybe somebody had the same problem and is kind enough to provide me with a solution.

My code looks like this (even though I believe this issue is outside of my influence):

```
this.divs = document.querySelectorAll(this.selector);
if(this.debug_level > 1) console.log("btn.length:"+this.divs.length + " for selector:"+this.selector);
    for(var i = 0; i<this.divs.length; i++) {
       this.divs[i].addEventListener("touchstart", this.bodyTouchStart);
       this.divs[i].addEventListener("touchmove", this.bodyTouchMove);
       this.divs[i].addEventListener("touchend", this.bodyTouchEnd);
    }

bodyTouchStart: function (e) {
    try {
         //alert("touchstart");
         var name = e.touches[0].identifier;
         if(this.debug_level > 1) console.log(e.touches[0]);
         pager.makeTouchDist(name);

         pager.touchdist[name].touchdistX = 0;
         pager.touchdist[name].touchdistY= 0;
         pager.touchdist[name].touchstartX= e.touches[0].screenX;
         pager.touchdist[name].touchstartY= e.touches[0].screenY;
         pager.touchdist[name].touchendX= e.touches[0].screenX;
         pager.touchdist[name].touchendY=e.touches[0].screenY;
    } catch(e) {
         if(this.debug_level > 0) console.log("pager:bodyTouchStart"+e.message);
    }
},
bodyTouchMove: function (e) {
     try {
         for(var i = 0; i<e.targetTouches.length; i++) {
             var touch = e.targetTouches[i];
             var name = touch.identifier;
             pager.touchdist[name].setTouchEndX(touch.pageX);
             pager.touchdist[name].setTouchEndY(touch.pageY);
          }
          if(pager.touchdist[name].touchdistX < -1*pager.threshold && pager.countState < pager.count - 1) {
          $("body").trigger("slideStart");
              pager.divs[0].style.marginLeft = pager.lastCompleteState + pager.touchdist[name].touchdistX + "px";
          } else if(pager.touchdist[name].touchdistX > pager.threshold && pager.countState > 0) {
              $("body").trigger("slideStart");
              pager.divs[0].style.marginLeft = pager.lastCompleteState + pager.touchdist[name].touchdistX + "px";
          }
     } catch(e) {
          if(this.debug_level > 0) console.log("pager:bodyTouchMove: "+e.message);
     }
},
```

Comment: makes sense really - if you're not actually touching the touch screen part of the screen then how would the device even know to fire a touch start event ? (and of course the OS needs to get the start event before it can detect the end event)

Comment: Well if I slide from of the screen into the screen it also does not fire

Comment: @CodeUniquely I edited the question for clarity

Comment: you are starting OFF the screen (so you do not get a start) - In order to get moves you need a have a start, in order to get an end you also need a have a start. A start is detected when the IOS 'feels' you putting your finger onto the glass or screen downwards / tap, but not when you slide the finger about (even if you started off screen)

Comment: Is there any way around this? Maybe through a Cordova plugin (iOS)?

Comment: you may need to ask why do you need to detect taps off the screen ?  Surely your apps contents are only going to render on the screen  (up to the screens maximum width and height). As this is all you have in order to show contents to people to interact with? How would you expect someone to click and drag on contents that they cannot actually see?  - Just some thoughts - but I am having some difficultly understanding why you need to do this?